# Error Trying to Install Precompiled OpenCV 4.8 on Raspberry Pi 4 64Bit

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi

I was recently shown a method to install a precompiled version of OpenCV from the following link:[Install Precompiled OpenCV 4.8 on Raspberry Pi](https://lindevs.com/install-precompiled-opencv-on-raspberry-pi/)

When I run the command `sudo apt install -y ./opencv_64.deb` I'm met with

```bash
Note, selecting 'opencv:arm64' instead of './opencv_64.deb
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 opencv:arm64 : Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0:arm64 (>= 1.18.4) but it is not installable
                Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:arm64 (>= 1.18.4) but it is not installable
                Depends: libavcodec58:arm64 (>= 4.3.2)
                Depends: libavformat58:arm64 (>= 4.3.2) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libavutil56:arm64 (>= 4.3.2) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libswscale5:arm64 (>= 4.3.2) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: python3-numpy:arm64 (>= 1.19.5) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Does anyone know how to fix, I'm new to Pi and OpenCV so any help is massive appreciated

Comment: As this is not a programming question within the scope defined by the [help/on-topic], it is off topic for Stack Overflow. For general operating system or application support, you may be able to find help on [raspberrypi.se], [su] or [unix.se], but be sure to follow their content guidelines to ensure an on-topic question.

Comment: The link doesn't work on Bookworm yet. Too early.

Comment: Check this on Bookworm http://rptl.io/venv

Comment: I found this https://orcacore.com/4-ways-install-opencv-debian-12-bookworm/ but doesn't work.